# Struct pointers in mixed C / C++ code

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I am having an issue calling a C function from C++. In particular, I have an instance of a class that has a C struct member variable. I am passing a pointer to this variable into a C function, which is called from a member function. I observe that the variable pointer address does not change inside and outside of the C function. However, the address to one of the struct fields does in fact change.

Code outline:

```
extern "C"
{
  #define ENAGLO
  #include <rtklib.h>
}

class GNSS
{
  protected: rtcm_t rtcm;   // A C struct type in rtklib.h.
  public: ~GNSS() { free_rtcm(&rtcm); }
  public: GNSS() { init_rtcm(&rtcm); } 
  public: Load() { 

    // Add some stuff to the rtcm.obs element

    // This is the problematic line. If one were to read the address
    // of rtcm.nbyte inside and outside of the function below, its
    // address is different! Thus, if the gen_rtcm3 function sets
    // rtcm->nbyte = 3, it does not persist back into C++.
    gen_rtcm3(&rtcm, 1001, 0);
  }
}
```

The rtklib.h and source files are available here: [RTKLIB](https://github.com/tomojitakasu/RTKLIB/tree/rtklib_2.4.3/src)

I am using GCC 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

UPDATE: CMake is used to build both the RTKLIB library and C++ code in the following way. I've checked, and it doesn't seem to make a difference if -O3 is removed.

```
# Find all RTKLIB source files
set(RTKLIB_SOURCES 
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/ephemeris.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/ppp.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/preceph.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcvraw.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rinex.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/sbas.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rtkpos.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/datum.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rtcm3.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/options.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rtkcmn.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rtcm2.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/stream.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/ionex.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/binex.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/rt17.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/gw10.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/nvs.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/ublox.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/septentrio.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/ss2.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/rcvlex.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/novatel.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/javad.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/skytraq.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rcv/crescent.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/convkml.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/pntpos.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rtcm.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/ppp_ar.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/geoid.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rtcm3e.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/solution.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/streamsvr.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rtklib.h
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/rtksvr.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/qzslex.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/lambda.c
  thirdparty/RTKLIB/src/tle.c
)

# Create a rtklib library
add_library(crates_gnss_rtklib ${RTKLIB_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(crates_gnss_rtklib    
  ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}
  ${BLAS_LIBRARIES}
  ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
  ${MATH_LIBRARY}
  ${RT_LIBRARY}
)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(crates_gnss_rtklib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-O3 -DTRACE -DENAGLO -DENAGAL -DENAQZS -DNFREQ=3")

# Crate a gazebo receiver
add_library(crates_gnss_plugin src/GNSS.cc)
target_link_libraries(crates_gnss_plugin    
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} 
  ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES} 
  crates_gnss_rtklib
)

# THIS IS THE LINE THAT WAS ULTIMATELY NEEDED!
#SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(crates_gnss_plugin PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-O3 -DTRACE -DENAGLO -DENAGAL -DENAQZS -DNFREQ=3")
```

Comment: How was the library compiled? Is `sizeof(rtcm_t)` the same for the C++ code and the C code? I have a theory that perhaps the exact layout of `rtcm_t` isn't consistent between your C++ compilation and the C compilation (perhaps different padding, or different member sizes, or different structure definitions (i.e. C lib is version 1, but C++ is using a version 2 header)).

Comment: Print out `sizeof(rtcm_t)` and `offsetof(rtcm_t, x)` for all fields `x` in `rtcm_t`, both in the C portion of your code and in the C++ portion. Everything should match. If there is a mismatch, you have incompatible compilers, or incompatible compilation flags, or different sets of header files for C and C++.

Comment: You guys were spot on -- there are two different rtcm_t sizes in C and C++ respectively. Values -- C++ : 243096, C : 314832. At least now I know the source of the issue!

Comment: I finally worked out that it was a compile flag issue. I had compiled RTKLIB into a shared library with a different set of compile flags than the C++ code that linked against it. This lead to a different struct size and runtime issues. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked out that it was a compile flag issue. I had compiled RTKLIB into a shared library with a different set of compile flags than the C++ code that linked against it. This lead to a different struct size and runtime issues.